# why does this graphql update all records?

Tags: graphql, hasura

```
mutation {
  update_orders(where: { status: null }, _set: {status: OPEN } ) {
    returning {
      id
      status
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a bug, or do I misunderstand null in graphql? This query is updating ALL orders. I only intended to update orders where status is null. What's going on here?

Cheers!

Comment: not query is the most important - but backend implementation - what args and **how** it supports - check it (api specs) then adjust query if needed, there is no universal/standarized syntax for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mutation {
  update_orders(where: { status: { _is_null: true } }, _set: { status: OPEN } ) {
    returning {
      id
      status
    }
  }
}
```

relevant documentation: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html#filter-or-check-for-null-values-is-null